# Determine Call Connected Event

Tags: android, phone-call

In the Outgoing call, i need to identify when the call connects to the recipient network that is when the recipient phone starts ringing.
I need to capture the time taken by the network in the call connection establishment.

Comment: Cool. What is your specific question?

Comment: count milliseconds during the conversations

Comment: As mentioned. How to capture the call connect event programmatically .

Comment: outgoing call made ---> 2. network looks for the target phone( meanwhile we hear beeps ) ---> 3.Ring goes on the target phone ---> 4. target phone picks the call ---> 5.call Ended . Need to identify event 3 here.  Thanks.